# Is Exposed Drywall After a Ceiling Leak an Asbestos Concern?

Tags: drywall, leak, mold, asbestos

Back in March we had a leak in the ceiling of my daughter’s room.  During heavy rain, a spot where the drywall panels meet bubbled up.  At the time, I popped the bubble and pulled back a fair amount of the paint and some drywall paper (?) ripped off with it.   I was trying to make sure the moisture hadn’t spread (it hadn’t). The ceiling is still in the same condition, and it’s eight months later (see photo)

We’re waiting til our roof is replaced in a couple of weeks to see if any obvious mold or further water damaged has occurred.  If the roofers don’t see anything from above, we’ll hire someone to open part of the ceiling to check for mold and repair.

This brings me to my question.  The room is an addition from 1960-ish. I recently discovered that joint compound from back then can contain asbestos.  What’s done is done as far as the paint and paper being ripped back.  But is it dangerous that ceiling has been sitting in this state for the last 9 months?  Could it be shedding asbestos night after night?  It’s not like anyone is touching or disturbing it at this point. My daughter sleeps in there every night, and that makes me nervous.  Am I being a little too paranoid?   Thanks in advance.

Note:  This question was flagged as being too similar to another question.  I don’t agree - the other question was about gaping drywall holes all over the house that had removed lead piping behind it.  This is about some prior surface disturbance to 2 sheets of drywall.  The ceiling is still in the same condition 8 months later.  I’m concerned that just by the AC running in the room, or the doors being opened and closed - that the ceiling could still be releasing fibers IF there was asbestos in the joint compound.  Is that concern misguided?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless you've got little fibers falling on everything, **don't worry**.  Asbestos != plutonium. More of an issue - and even that really isn't a big deal in a situation like this - is the layers of lead paint that fell down in the process of all this. Just clean up and move on.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact :  i tested for lead paint in multiple spots, and it all came back negative.  I would have tested for asbestos, but from what I’m reading it’s better to leave undisturbed.

Comment: No lead paint is great! As far as asbestos - if you need to actually sand down what is there *and* it turned out to be asbestos *and* you didn't wear a mask then it could be a minor issue. Even then *probably* not because the big issue is repeated exposure (year after year working with the stuff every day). If you're really that concerned, put on a mask, cut out the damaged areas (that can be done without producing much dust) and put up fresh drywall - at $ 15 a sheet it would take a lot of drywall to pay for even a little bit of professional "mitigation". Just cut it out - which will make it

Comment: easier to make it look good and you won't have to worry about whether you missed some moldy parts, etc.

Comment: Or this? [How likely is it that my 1980 home has asbestos in the drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/how-likely-is-it-that-my-1980-home-has-asbestos-in-the-drywall)

Comment: Or this? [What is my risk of asbestos exposure due to a previous drywall work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207044/what-is-my-risk-of-asbestos-exposure-due-to-a-previous-drywall-work)

Comment: Doesn't look like popcorn, but hard to see detail.  Looks like standard drywall mud to me, which shouldn't have asbestos.

Comment: It wasn't closed because the _question_ is the same, but because the _answer_ is the same. [Closing as duplicate.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

> Could it be shedding asbestos night after night?

Yes, it *could* but since, as you said, it's no longer being disturbed, it's highly unlikely. Also, as noted in the comments, a one-time (or short-term) exposure to some asbestos is not very likely to cause any damage, it's long-term, unprotected exposure that caused so many problems for those who worked in factories making asbestos-based products and those who installed said products.

If you are really worried, then slap a quick coat of paint over it to hold everything in place for another couple of months until the roof is repaired. Then, put on a good dust mask (which you should use for tearing out drywall anyway - the gypsum dust is an eye and lung irritant, too), then rip out all the damaged drywall and replace it.